# Question about the Pertussis/Whooping Cough Vaccine?

Tags: visa, immigration, medical, k1-visa

UK guy looking to move to the US here.

I received Parts 1/2/3 of the Pertussis/Whooping Couch vaccine, however I didn't get my booster. I am up to date on Polio, Tetanus and Diphtheria.

Do I need to go and get the Pertussis booster, or am I okay because I received it as a kid, just no booster?

Thanks